# move file to sharepoint via php/curl

Tags: php, file, curl, sharepoint, upload

I use the following php code to upload an html file to a sharepoint :

```
$the_file = file_get_contents("".realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/<file_name>.htm");//Note: the file already exists in the dir


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<usr>:<pass>");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://<xxxx>.sharepoint.com/sites/<xxx>/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post = array('file_contents' => "the_file");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo json_encode('Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
else {
    
    echo ($response);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Everything looks good, the $response gives me :

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://<xxxx>.sharepoint.com/sites/<xxxx>/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2Fsites%2F<xxx>%2FShared%20Documents%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

But when I go in the sharepoint (by clicking on the link above), there is no trace of the file !?!

Can somebody tells me what I am doing wrong or missing ?

Thank you
Andreas

According to the output message, I expected that the file was uploaded which is not the case !?!

Comment: First, “move” and the web rarely go together. Instead you can “upload” or “copy” something and then manually delete it. Second, I think the error message you are seeing is a 302 redirect, possibly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/designer/object-moved-when-connecting-sharepoint-site

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes my wording is not exact. I meant "copy" actually. The curl does not have an error, but it says it is successfully and gives the output on the $response variable telling me where my file is (with the link) - actually it is the way I understand the output of $response. This is why I am not sure I am facing a 302 error.

Comment: Just tried with this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and all worked fine. Frustration is still here why my code above do not work

Comment: I don’t know anything about Sharepoint, but do you have any documentation showing that’s how to upload a file?

Comment: @andreas, Is your issue got resolved? I am also facing same issue where file is missing from the SharePoint location.

Comment: @SDLBeginner. I solved my issue from a business perspective since I changed the way to do (see previous comment). I did not solve my original technical issue using curl to send file in sharepoint